# Can we prove that the "speed" of convergence implied by LNN is proportional to $\sqrt n$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\overline X_n$ be the average of $n$ i.i.d. instances of the random variable $X$. Let's say $E(x)=0$ for simplicity. The CLT roughly says that $\overline X_n$ is distributed normally around its mean. If you plot the density of $\overline X_n$, though, you might be dissapointed, because you don't get a bell curve, you get a spike. The problem, of course, is that as $n$ increases, its distribution *does* approach a bell curve, but it also becomes thinner and thinner thanks to the LLN. We can correct for this by putting some constant factor in front of $\overline X_n$ in order to "stretch out" the distribution. This constant would have to increase with $n$: the CLT tells us that in some sense, the "correct" constant is $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$.

In other words, the "width" of the distribution of $\overline X_n$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\sqrt n$. How can we prove this result without appealing to CLT (as a preliminary to CLT, say, to motivate the formula).

Can we prove, for example, that $\epsilon_p$ such that $P(|\overline X_n-E(X)| > \epsilon_p) < p$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$, in some sense, for small $p$?

I'm mostly interested in elementary proofs (not using anything more advanced than what you'd find in a proof of LLN or CLT, say).

Comment: The sum of $n$ independent random variables of variance $\sigma^2$ has variance $n\sigma^2$.

Comment: @Rahul And so the standard deviation of $\overline X_n$ is $\frac {s} {\sqrt n}$, where $s$ is the standard deviation of $X$. But this assumes that standard deviation is a good way to measure the "width" of a distribution. That's why I tried to formulate the question more precisely in the second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: There is a precise sense in which the standard deviation measures the width of a distribution, namely, it is the root-mean-square distance from the mean.

Answer (score 1):

Since if you average many i.i.d. instances of $X$ based on a distribution with undefined second moment, the width of the distribution *doesn't* always go to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ (In fact, you may not get a "spike"), you need to say that the second moment exists and is finite.

And once you have to inject and use information about the second moment, you are pretty much there to the central limit theorem anyway.